# How can a --HEAD dependency be specified in homebrew-bundle

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to specify the following command into a `Brewfile` for use in [`homebrew-bundle`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle):

```
brew install --HEAD open-ocd
```

I can get a normal install to work if the `Brewfile` contains:

```
brew "open-ocd"
```

But I don't see any examples on how to properly specify `--HEAD` within a `Brewfile`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `brew dump` I was able to determine that the correct `Brewfile` is:

```
brew "open-ocd", args: ["HEAD"]
```